# Stopping screen resolution changing layout of python game

Tags: python, layout, tkinter, screen, resolution

I'm making my program on a 1200 by 800 screen, but when I tried to run it at school, which is (I think) 1280 by 1024, the format changes a lot and gets all messed up. In python, is there a way to stop a different sized screen from changing how the program looks?

I am using tkinter and have tk.resizable(0, 0) which stops the user from pulling the bottom right corner and changing the size of the window - However, tk.resizable only stops the user from changing the size of the window.

My code for drawing the canvas is:

```
global tk
tk = Tk()
VarExt = 0
tk.title("Pong Revolution - Version 9.2.8")#Title at top of window
tk.resizable(0, 0) #stops window being resizable
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=700, height=700, bg='black',)
```

Comment: Ensure your game only runs in a fixed size and doesn't respond to resize events. We'd need to see the code your using to draw the game to be more specific. For example are you using PyGame? Something else?

Comment: The window shouldn't magically grow to fit a larger screen unless you tell it to. We'll need to see more of your code in order to help you.

Comment: It doesnt grow to fit the whole screen, it stays the same shape (700 by 700) but for some reason it changes. I was assuming it was because of the screen change, but could it be it comes out different on different operating systems? I have an 'X' which is 600 size font, but takes 1/2 to 2/3 of the 700 tall screen, but at school it goes to the size you would expect for 600 font - 6/7th of the height of the canvas.